# Is Pyro signal safe?

Tags: python, signals, pyro

I have been using Pyro 3 for a little while now, with great success, but occasionally I have noticed, that when a signal such as SIGHUP or SIGINT arrives while Pyro is doing some remote communications, the process hangs, hence the question, is Pyro signal safe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the issue here is by default Python sets up a handlers for SIGINT and SIGTERM which raise exceptions. If you therfore receive a signal while doing some Pyro comms, the exception is raised, and off it goes to look for an appropriate except clause, not finishing what it was doing, if you then try and use Pyro again, for example in the except/finally clause, you can get issues. In my case it was sending some messages from finally to a log via a queue which was proxied to another process using Pyro.